# Program won't compile because of brackets

Tags: java, javac

I'm writing a game in Java and after compiling it and debugging, the only error was that it reach the end of the file while parsing.

I looked and made sure all the brackets were balanced. I realized I was missing a closing bracket, so I added one where it should be. After compiling again, there were even more errors, as if there were misplaced brackets.

Below is the version without the bracket on line 94. I understand entire files are not ideal to post, but the issue is not specific to a few lines of the code that I am aware of.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
public class NATO{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        float finalScore = 0;
        float numberCompleted = 0;
        float numberCorrect = 0;
        int gameLength = 10;
        boolean playing = true;

        String A = "Alpha";
        String B = "Beta";
        String C = "Charlie";
        String D = "Delta";
        String E = "Echo";
        String F = "Foxtrot";
        String G = "Golf";
        String H = "Hotel";
        String I = "India";
        String J = "Juliett";
        String K = "Kilo";
        String L = "Lima";
        String M = "Mike";
        String N = "November";
        String O = "Oscar";
        String P = "Papa";
        String Q = "Quebec";
        String R = "Romeo";
        String S = "Sierra";
        String T = "Tango";
        String U = "Uniform";
        String V = "Victor";
        String W = "Whiskey";
        String X = "Xylophone";
        String Y = "Yankee";
        String Z = "Zulu";

        while(playing == true) {

            try {
                InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
                System.out.println("Welcome to the NATO speed game! Press [ENTER] to start...");
            }

            catch (IOEXCEPTION ioe) {
                System.out.println("Index out of bounds exception raised ^");
            }

            System.out.println("Game starting in 3...");
            System.out.println("Game starting in 2...");
            System.out.println("Game starting in 1...");

            while(numberCompleted <= gameLength){
                int rnd = Random().nextInt(args.length);
                String word = args[rnd];
                System.out.println(word.charAt(1));
                System.out.println(": ");
                String answerIncludingSpaces = System.in.nextLine;
                String answerUncapitalized = answerIncludingSpaces.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
                String answer = answerUncapitalized.charAt(1).toUpperCase;

                if(answer != word) {
                    float numberCompleted = numberCompleted + 1;
                }

                else if(answer == word){
                    float numberCorrect = numberCorrect + 1;
                }

                else {
                    System.out.println("Something went wrong. Please restart the game.");
                    break;
                }
            }

            float finalScore = (numberCorrect / numberCompleted);
            System.out.println("Game over.");
            System.out.println("Your score was " + finalScore + ". Would you like to play again? Y/N");

            if(System.nextLine.toUpperCase == "Y") {
                continue;
            }

            else {
                system.out.println("Thank you for playing!");
                break;
            }

        }

    }
}
```

The error message(s) it shows me when I do add the bracket on line 94:

https://pastebin.com/6E9DNdkA

Comment: I can see there is typo mistake in "IOEXCEPTION" , it should be IOException , and you've not imported the classes whom functionality you've used like , import java.io.BufferedReader , java.io.InputStreamReader . There are typo errors if you will try to debug them , you will find error , there is nothing wrong with sublime editor.

Comment: There are lot of errors in this program

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193554/pies-den @heroK

Answer (score 5):

You are missing imports for `InputStreamReader` and `BufferedReader`. `system` and `IOEXCEPTION` are not capitalized correctly (and `IOException` will require an import when spelled correctly). You have some methods that you don't put parentheses after (e.g. `nextLine` on line 83). You need to put `new` before `Random()` on line 57.

Since `finalScore` is already declared as a `float` on line 7, you need to remove the `float` before it on line 79. You should only declare the type of a variable when you are creating it. With the second `float` declaration on line 79, it is trying to create a second `finalScore` variable which fails, because you can't have 2 variables with the same name. Removing the `float` declaration on that line will make it correctly modify the existing `finalScore` variable. This same idea applies to other places like `numberCompleted` on line 66 and `numberCorrect` on line 70.

Also, on line 63 you need to do `Character.toUpperCase(answerUncapitalized.charAt(1))`. Currently you are trying to call `toUpperCase` on a `char`, and primitives don't have methods, so that is incorrect.

But really, you should use an application that helps you with this, such as Eclipse. I copied and pasted this in Eclipse and it made it very easy to see where the issues are, and suggested appropriate fixes for some of them.

Comment: I'll fix up the things you mentioned and switch to Eclipse as soon as I'm home to work on this. My teacher has always had us use BlueJ, but I don't really like its layout. He recommended I use Sublime instead if I wanted, and I haven't really noticed how little help it gives you until I started doing my own projects. Thank you for your suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

If the question is "*why does addition of one bracket cause so many more compile errors to be reported?*", then the answer is that presence of syntax errors (like missing bracket) will cause compilers to abort before even starting to detect more 'sophisticated' errors.

Think of it as a game in two (or more) rounds:

- Can we (compiler & programmer) agree that this is syntactically correct Java?

  - if answer is "no", abort.
  - if answer is "yes", we proceed.
- Can we agree that all names are resolvable?

  - if answer is "no" ...

Etc.

Motivation is: if we don't agree even on the syntax level, than any further errors are likely off the mark, i.e., more confusing than helping.

Comment: I figure then as someone who is pretty new to Java I should use a program that helps with syntax errors better than Sublime. Thank you!